# Self signed SSL certificate imported in ACM does not work with nginx

Tags: ssl, openssl, aws-certificate-manager

I've created an SSL certificate like this:

`openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout mycert.key -out mycert.csr`

I filled all required information, especially `Common Name (eg, fully qualified host name) []:` with `test.mydomain.com` and I got the files `mycert.csr` and `mycert.key`

Then, to generate the cetificate, I ran the command:

`openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in mycert.csr -signkey mycert.key -out mycert.crt`

Then I used ACM console https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/acm/home and I imported a new cert using as **Certificate body** `mycert.crt` and as **Certificate private key** `mycert.key`.

Then, I created an **EC2** instances with Amazon Linux 2023 and I assigned an Elastic IP. In this instance I installed an *NGINX* server as *reverse proxy* for my nodejs application.  I used this configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name test.mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/certs/mycert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certs/mycert.key;

    location / {
        # My nodejs application lists to 8081 port
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Using **Route53** I created an A record to map the Elastic IP with `test.mydomain.com`.

**The problem** is when I access to `https://test.mydomain.com` using a browser it says that it is **not a secure connection** like it can't validate ssl cert.

Some ideas?

Comment: Not programming or development, but your cert is not signed by a trusted CA, and could easily have been created by anybody, such as a criminal or enemy running a fake, malicious and harmful server. To make it trusted, you must import it into the 'root CA' store used by the browser; this varies and you didn't say which browser(s). Further, using Common Name to identify an HTTPS (web) server was replaced over a decade ago with SubjectAlternativeName (SAN), and _most_ browsers today will no longer use CN; there are many Qs about setting SAN in OpenSSL on this and other Stacks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think the main idea of importing the certificate into ACM is that it acts as a Certificate Authority and recognizes this untrusted certificate. am I wrong?

Comment: ACM _is_ a subordinate CA and can _issue_ a _new_ certificate to you under a generally trusted root (Starfield), but nobody, including ACM, can alter an existing cert issued by somebody else. The purpose of importing an existing cert-and-key is to allow it to be used, _instead_ of an ACM-issued cert, by various Amazon services that are designed to use ACM.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I think this is the question answer if you want to post it

Comment: This is not a programming or development issue, and therefore offtopic; that's why I didn't post an answer in the first place.